# Trying to get contents of web page with php

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to get content from the page below. For my own purpose, i am just interested on the  tag so then i could put it into an array for when i send the bot response back to Twitter API with their appropriate method. Here's what i tried:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
         <conversation convo_id="$convo_id">
         <bot_name>infobot2012</bot_name>
         <user_name>User</user_name>
         <user_id value='2' />
         <usersay>$say</usersay>
         <botsay>Internal error detected. Please inform my botmaster. </botsay>
         </conversation>


         $url = "http://localhost/Program-O/chatbot/conversation_start.php?say=$say&  
         hello&convo_id=$convo_id&bot_id=$bot_id&format=xml";

         get_url_contents($url)
         $crl = curl_init(); //getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
         $timeout = 5;
         curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
         curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
         $ret = curl_exec($crl);
         curl_close($crl);
         return $ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semi-colon on the line above it:

```
get_url_contents($url)
```

should be

```
get_url_contents($url);
```

Comment: The joy of the random downvote, it wasn't me by the way just here to let you know I enjoy these too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function get_url_contents($url) {
    $crl = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}

$url = "http://localhost/Program-O/chatbot/conversation_start.php?say=" . $say . "&hello&convo_id=" . $convo_id . "&bot_id=" . $bot_id . "&format=xml";

echo get_url_contents ($url);
```